# storing a 64-bit pointer in a 32-bit integer, provided max virtual memory address <= UINT32_MAX (e.g., when RAM size <= 4GB)

Tags: c, pointers, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, virtual-memory

Are there any platforms (if so, which?) where something like the following can be done, provided that a runtime check confirms that there is no more than 4GB of virtual memory (or RAM) available?

```
// 1) cast pointer to void pointer
// 2) cast void pointer to uint64 type
// 3) set most significant bytes of uint64 type to 0 (might be wrong choice)
// 4) store as uint32 type
uint32_t trimmed_pointer = (uint64_t) (void *) pointer & 0x00000000ffffffff;
```

and to get back the original pointer:

```
same_as_before_t *pointer = (void *) (uint64_t) trimmed_pointer
```

I realize this would probably be a terrible hack and entirely dependent on how the OS's memory manager implements virtual memory (as well as the compiler?), so I'm asking this purely out of curiosity.

Comment: Well, if the OS decides that virtual memory always goes to the lower doubleword, then this works, but honestly I don't know ow any platform that guarantees this.

Comment: I can tell you that Mac OS X won't meet your requirements.  Stack variables are placed at an address with a number of the high-order 32-bits set (e.g. 0x7FFF_5468_74DC).  (Example code: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&x);
    return 0;
}`

Comment: Yes, this would probably "work" on any platform that meets those constraints...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting. I might try to find out what 64to32 bitmask would work on what platform.

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question?

Comment: I think this is perhaps bordering on not being a practical problem. But I was actually asking the question to see if there was some other motivation that might be useful to potential answerers.#

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If a practical reason is really necessary, I'd argue that in a controlled environment (like one individual running such code on his or her own machine only) the uint32_t representation would save space. If you have a very large array full of pointers (or structs containing pointers), the memory savings would allow performance benefits on X86_64 (because of CPU caching).

Answer (score 3):

In order to aid porting crufty, old 32-bit programs that assumed that pointers could be safely stored in 32-bit integer types, Windows still respects the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag in the PE header for 64-bit programs.

If that flag isn't set in the program's header, the system will not allocate an address above 2GB to the process.

By default for 64-bit builds, the linker sets the flag (ie., by default the address space for a 64-bit program will *not* be limited).  If you want to indicate that your 64-bit program should not be given any address space above 2GB, pass the `/largeaddressaware:no` option to the linker when the program is built. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384271.aspx for details.

Keep in mind that this feature is intended to help port programs that don't handle pointers properly - not to enable you to write such programs.  Also keep in mind the important fact that virtual addresses have little to do with physical addresses (in other words, even if you have less than 4GB of RAM, the system could still use virtual addresses in the terabyte range).

Answer (score 2):

This would work on a 64-bit Windows if the program is not marked as [Large-Address Aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (or rather, is explicitly marked as *not* Aware), since it's explicitly what Windows does in that case, with just one caveat: If I remember correctly, pointers should be sign-extended when converting back to 64 bits.

Not that it would matter anyway, since all "negative" pointers are accessible only to kernel code and should not be visible in userspace code (the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO` flag also protects the program from the `/3GB` kernel switch which would make this affirmation false).

Of course, it's only read when starting an EXE file: If an Aware EXE loads a non-Aware DLL, boom!

Comment: No, a 64 bit process uses 64 bit pointers. Large address aware only has meaning for a 32 bit process.

Comment: Well, I beg your pardon. I was mistaken.

Comment: @David, the link in Michael Burr's answer seems to indicate that you can disable largeaddressaware for 64-bit processes.  This would result in Windows returning you only pointers smaller than 4GB.